# How do I upload a file without browsing for the file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am learning how to work with FileUpload control in ASP.NET. I am a little curious whether tis possible to upload a file without having to browse for it, that is, by knowing the path of the file I want to upload.

Pseudo Example:

```
 filepath = "C:\temp\file.txt"
 FileUpload1.SaveAs( ..., filepath ,...)
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to perform this by using other ways like httppostfile, etc...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons, browsers typically prevent access to local file system objects that have not been selected by the file upload.

Most file uploads also require a **human action** to select the file path; that is, they prevent the file path from being specified with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

What if you changed your code to:

```
filepath = "C:\documents\mypasswords.txt"
FileUpload1.SaveAs( ..., filepath ,...)
```

and this file was uploaded automatically to your server without me, as a user of your site, knowing about it? Well, I wouldn't be a happy user of your site. So luckily that's not possible.